# Doctrine ORM 2 Embeddables and References

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Doctrine ORM 2.5 adds embeddables to classes, [as explained here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html). What I want to know if the following is doable, and if so, how.

```
<?php

/** @Entity */
class User
{
    /** @Embedded(class = "Address") */
    private $address;
}

/** @Embeddable */
class Address
{
    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    private $street;

    ...
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="City")
     * @JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $city;
}

/** @Entity */
class City
{
    ...
}
```

I suppose that, as `Address` and `User` are part of the same table, `City` should save a reference to `User` in the database. But I'm unsure if this is even possible. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try it out? BTW you can validate your entities with doctrine orm:validate-schema this will tell you if your entities are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the tutorial states:

> In terms of your database schema, Doctrine will automatically inline all columns from the Address class into the table of the User class, just as if you had declared them directly there.

What happens is that the only tables generated are `User` and `City`. The information of the `Address` is directly merged into the `User` table. For your test case, this results in the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE User (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, address_street VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, address_postalCode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, address_country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE City (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

As you can see, the relation to City is completely missing, since this functionality is currently not implemented (yet). For now you need to keep the relations out of the embeddables:

```
<?php

/** @Entity */
class User {
    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Id()
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @Embedded(class = "Address") */
    private $address;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="City") */
    private $city;
}
```

This generates the tables as you would probably expect them, including the relation to the city:

```
CREATE TABLE User (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, city_id INT DEFAULT NULL, address_street VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, address_postalCode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, address_country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_E0C1DE1C8BAC62AF (city_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE City (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE User ADD CONSTRAINT FK_E0C1DE1C8BAC62AF FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES City (id);
```

I would suggest you post to the [doctrine-user mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/doctrine-user), they have been quite responsive to [similar questions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/xDiL65QV_sM).

Comment: Embeddable asstiations wouldn't be implemented ever: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4291 :-(